# Spring resourceHandler pattern fails for index-page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to map resourceHandlers to resourceLocations in a Spring MVC application, but somehow I can't make the mapping between /* and my index.html work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mySpringApp.web.controller"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*", "/", "").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/");

    }

    ...
```

The requests I make returns the following:

- http://localhost:8080/ - 404
- http://localhost:8080/index.html - 200(returns the index-file that I wan't on /* )
- http://localhost:8080/assets/main.js - 200(returns one of the files
  located in my assets-folder)

Any idea why the index-mapping fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **http://localhost:8080/** is requested, spring is looking for a controller with a mapping looking like `@RequestMapping("")` or `@RequestMapping("/")`, which you do not have.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/*", "/", "").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html");
```

not serving **index file** because:
you are simply not specifying what resource you want spring to serve.

#### possible solutions

- Write a controller

  ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/")
   public String index() {
       return "redirect:index.html";
   }
  ```
- Refactor `addResourceHandlers()`

  ```
  registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/static/");
  ```

Note that `addResourceHandler` is adding a "pattern" while `addResourceLocation` is telling spring where exactly/physically to find the requested resource.

Comment: Aaaah, so I'm trying to serve a location rather than a resource! Makes sense! Thank you!